# wxPython: Is it possible to manage the hover color of a button?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to create a dark theme for my wxPython app, and I'm wondering if I can control the hover color of a button.

```
import wx

class AppButton(wx.Button):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.SetLabel('Test')
        self.SetOwnBackgroundColour('#131313')
        self.SetOwnForegroundColour('white')
        self.SetPosition((100,100))

class Exampple(wx.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.SetSize(300,300)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#151719')
        self.Center()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button = AppButton(panel)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Exampple(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

There are SetOwnBackgroundColour and SetOwnForegroundColour methods, but is there something like SetOwnHoverColor or maybe a special event like wx.EVT_HOVER? Because the default light blue hover color is not what I want in my dark theme. I tried using EVT_ENTER_WINDOW and EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW and also EVT_MOTION, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So Close!

`wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW` and `wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW` will do the job, I guess you missed the implementation somehow.

```
import wx

class AppButton(wx.Button):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.SetLabel('Test')
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')
        self.SetForegroundColour('white')
        self.SetPosition((100,100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnHover)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnUnHover)
        
    def OnHover(self, event):
        print("Enter",event.Entering(), "Leave",event.Leaving())
        self.SetBackgroundColour('maroon')       
        self.SetForegroundColour('yellow')
        event.Skip()
        
    def OnUnHover(self, event):
        print("Enter",event.Entering(), "Leave",event.Leaving())
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black') 
        self.SetForegroundColour('white')
        event.Skip()

class Exampple(wx.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.SetSize(300,300)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#151719')
        self.Center()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button = AppButton(panel)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Exampple(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Strange, it only works when I hold the right-click, but when i hover over the button the color is still default.. win10, python 3.6.1, wxpython 4.1.1 btw

Comment: Strange indeed. This works happily on Linux python 3.8 wxpython 4.2 and I would expect it to work on every other flavour too. Stick a `print("Enter",event.Entering(), "Leave",event.Leaving())` in one or both of the callbacks, to see if they are being triggered.

Comment: All events are handled as expected. I also noticed that the button text is recolored yellow on hovering, but the background color stays the default. Perhaps the Windows version has some other event that has a higher priority than `wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW`. Anyway, thanks for your answers.

Comment: Try using `self.SetBackgroundColour()` rather than `self.SetOwnBackgroundColour()` and also try `event.Skip()`